# Best Indexing for Performance - MySQL

Tags: performance, index, mysql-5.7

I have a question related performance DB MySQL. I have querying like this with big data inside :

```
SELECT 
       * 
FROM 
       tableA a 
       INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.id AND a.code = b.code
       INNER JOIN tableC c ON a.uniq = c.uniq
WHERE
       a.date = '2020-01-01'
       AND a.type = 'X'
       AND b.merk =  'New';
```

My question is, what is better using single index or multi-column index?

Ex :

Index in tableA (Example1) :

- idx1 (merk, code, date, type)
- idx2 (date)
- idx3 (merk)
- idx4 (code)
- idx5 (type)

Index in tableA (Example2) :

- idx1 (merk, code, date, type)
- idx2 (merk, code)
- idx3 (date, type)

What is better? Example1 or Example2? And please explain it.

**Notes** : maybe tableA will got varian WHERE on another query for future

Thank you

Comment: A good habit when you ask query optimization questions is to include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in your query. As text please, not as screenshots. Readers want to know your data types, indexes, and constraints, and they may want to copy these tables to do some tests, and that's not possible if you post images. Also you should include the result of `EXPLAIN` for the query you are trying to optimize. Help us to help you!

Answer (score 0):

The engine will only be able to make use of one index per table so while the other indexes may help you in the future with other queries, their benefit will be limited in assisting you with this particular query.

Given what we know about your query and limited knowledge of the table and the insert pattern, I would suggest the following.

```
Table A - (Date, Type)
Table B - (merk, ID, Code)
Table C - (Uniq)
```

Of course, if you were able to limit the result set columns (getting rid of the SELECT *) then further columns in the index could be of benefit.

These indexes above will allow the engine to seek quickly and get quickly to the rows that it wants.

I do have one question about the "merk" on Table B.  If that is something like a status that changes then I would not index on it, leaving just an index on ID and Code.  If the value of the field changes frequently then it is usually a poor index candidate as it will cause much fragmentation.

Comment: if i build some query include table B and just using `merk` on `JOIN/WHERE/ORDER/GROUP`, that's index on table B has a good performance?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Query Optimization](https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization)

Answer (score -1):

The only way to figure out the best indexing strategy for a specific environment is to test it. That doesn't mean you can't follow some best practices, but if this is a production server, you need to test.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/197848)

Answer (score -2):

The best result can be estimated with the next indexes:

```
Table A - (id, uniq, date, code, type)
Table B - (id, code, merk)
Table C - (uniq)
```